# Making an autocmd conditional

Tags: autocmd, python

I have the official [black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations/editors.html#vim) plugin installed in vim. I have in my vimrc:

```
au FileType python autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> Black
```

This works fine, but I would like to be able to disable the autoformatting in some situations. I tried this:

```
au FileType python autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> if get(b:, 'black_enabled', 1) | Black | endif
```

That successfully *disables* formatting if I `let b:black_enabled=0`, but when `black_enabled=1` (or is unset), that results in:

```
Error detected while processing function black#Black:
line    4:
E684: list index out of range: 1
E684: list index out of range: 1
```

...and then Black appears to run anyway.

What's wrong with my syntax that it's causing errors?

Comment: How is the `Black` command defined? Does it have the `-bar` attribute? If it doesn't it will see `| endif` as its arguments. You can check whether the `-bar` attribute was used by running `:command Black` and checking if the first column contains a `|`.

Comment: The function is defined [here](https://github.com/psf/black/blob/main/autoload/black.vim#L204). I'm a little confused by your comment; I thought `|` was the vimscript command separator (like `;` in the shell), so I wouldn't expect a function definition to influence how it behaves. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Not all commands see `|` as a separator; some see it as part of their arguments. Most notorious examples for the latter are `:g` and `:argdo`, `:bufdo` and `:windo`.

Comment: The link you provided points to the definition of the `Black()` function. What you need to check is the definition of the `:Black` command [here](https://github.com/psf/black/blob/3905173cb32922b580bad184e724586f359c8c7e/plugin/black.vim#L78). It does not include the `-bar` parameter, so `:Black` will see `|` as part of its arguments.

Comment: You might want to try if `:command! -bar -nargs=* -complete=customlist,BlackComplete Black :call black#Black(<f-args>)` before the `au`-command fixes your problem. If yes you can ask the maintainer(s) to include this change.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've come up with for now (that doesn't require any changes to the Black plugin) is to just call the underlying function directly:

```
au FileType python autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> if get(b:, 'black_enabled', 1) | call black#Black() | endif
```

This seems to work as intended.